# Angular 2 templates -Safe navigation operator for methods

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using the angular 2 **safe navigation operator** successfully for properties,  which the documentation states is for **property paths**, but what is the best approach for **methods paths?**

```
myObj?.myMethod().myProperty
```

gives the Exception:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'myProperty' of null in
>   [{{myObj?.myMethod().myProperty}}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In javascript, quote from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp):

> A JavaScript method is a property containing a function definition.

I don't see any problems why it shouldn't work like this:

```
{{myObj?.myMethod()?.myProperty}}
```

From [Angular.io cheat sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet):

> `<p>Employer: {{employer?.companyName}}</p>`
>
> The safe navigation operator (?) means that the employer field is optional and if undefined, **the rest of the expression should be ignored**